# Extraction a specific word from a column in a dataframe using python

Tags: python, feature-extraction

I have a Dataframe:

```
Job Title
CEO
Founder
Co-Founder
Co-founder, Executive Officer & Co-Managing Partner
Co-Founder and Systems/Software Developer 
Founder/CEO
```

I need to only keep the rows that have Founders and Co-Founders in them. Note that I will also have to account for capitalization, spaces, and other operations like "/" and ",".

---

Please let me know what to do.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you using Pandas?

Comment: Can you please provide a proper snapshot (or copied text) of the dataframe. Present one is difficult to follow.

Comment: Thanks for the response, actually after examining the data further I realized that I need to filter out only for Founders and not Co-Founders. Some fields would have Founder/CEO others would have Founder, Director. How do I filter only for "Founder"?

Comment: Yes, I am using Pandas. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using pandas you should be able to do something like this:

```
df = df[df['Job Title'].str.lower().contains('founder')]
```

That should account for both founder and co-founder, and will ignore case since it lowercases everything.

Comment: Thank you. Also wondering what if I need to filter specifically only for Founders and exclude Co-founders. Would that be possible?

As you can see in the data above this would include only the row with Founder and Founder/CEO.

Comment: You could always just add an and condition with `&` in the brackets to say contains founder and does not contain co-founder.